# Create new instance of T in case of template function without specific implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I try to create new type in nullptr case,
I getting many errors from linker,
Generally, "T" can be anything (bool, int, short, class and etc. ),

"data" decleration is:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> data;
```

Let's look at the following code:

```
T Stuff:getAttr(const std:string name)
{
    if (data.find(name) == data.end() || !data[name].has_value())
    {
        return T();
    }

    if(nullptr == data[name])
    {
        return T();
    }

    try
    {
        return std::any_cast<T>(data[name]);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return T();
    }
}
```

What is the good way to do that ?

Comment: "I getting many errors from linker" Please edit your question and provide the error information

Comment: What is `if(nullptr == data[name])` supposed to do?